# Build missing styles on paperclip errors out on missing bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, bundler

I've tried a bunch of different ways to do this and found a hack to get it working, but I'm trying to make sure I'm doing it correctly. I'm running Rails 4.1.9, and I've copied the code from build_missing_paperclip_styles, and when I deploy I get an error saying "bundle: command not found". I've pasted the stack trace at the end of this.

If I change this line

```
  execute "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles"
```

to this line:

```
  execute "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles"
```

it works. But other commands during deploy work fine with bundle and rake, so why doesn't this one?

Here's the relevant stack trace:

```
DEBUG [c7e11673] Command: cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
DEBUG [c7e11673]    bash: bundle: command not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ec2-user@example.com: cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles exit status: 127
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stdout: Nothing written
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stderr: bash: bundle: command not found

SSHKit::Command::Failed: cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles exit status: 127
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stdout: Nothing written
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stderr: bash: bundle: command not found

Tasks: TOP => deploy:build_missing_paperclip_styles
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ec2-user@example.com: cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles exit status: 127
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stdout: Nothing written
cd /home/ec2-user/code/current; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles stderr: bash: bundle: command not found
`
```